# sql server 2005 encoding problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

Ive got text file with utf-8 encoding with more then 2k lines of insert command. Now I would like to execute it as a sql script to insert data into database.

There is greek text with which there are problems. After inserting there are only ? characters, no greek letters.

sample insert statement is presented below:

```
INSERT INTO myDB.[MC_LIST] 
    ([id], [data], [author], [created], [language], [type_name], [position]) 
 VALUES 
    ('2086','<data><id>1</id><language>gr</language><szonelinkdest>/products/how-does-nioxin-works-page.aspx</szonelinkdest><szoneimgalt>alt</szoneimgalt><title>ΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΣΗ ΦΡΟΝΤΙΔΑΣ ΤΗΣ ΕΠΙΔΕΡΜΙΔΑΣ</title><szoneimg>/m/photo/box-4.jpg</szoneimg><szonedesc>Κάθε προϊόν lala περιέχει έναν εξειδικευμένο συνδυασμό συστατικών επιστημονικής προέλευσης. </szonedesc><szonelinkname>ΟΙ ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΕΣ ΜΑΣ</szonelinkname><szonetitle>ΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΣΗ ΦΡΟΝΤΙΔΑΣ ΤΗΣ ΕΠΙΔΕΡΜΙΔΑΣ</szonetitle></data>',null,'4/15/2011 3:47:47 PM','gr','1','2') ;
```

What to do to make it work ?

thanks for any help.

Btw do You know any software which can convert utf-8 file to utf-16 file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this database only supposed to contain greek text? In that case make sure that its collation is one of the greek collations and change the collation of all existing varchar columns.

If you need to be international then use nvarchar columns instead of varchar.

I'm guessing the data column is an xml column? That's also going to be fine.

If you're going with nvarchar or xml then alter the insert statements to insert nvarchar data by putting an N before the string constants, like this

```
N'<data><id>1</id><language>gr...
```